# Why subprocess.call works with any string only if parameters are separated in an array?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

If I prepare a command line like this:

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -i '" + param1 + "' -o '" + param2 + "'
```

And try to use it with subprocess.call or os.system it may work or not depending of which characters param1 or param2 contain. When it fails the exception raised is similar to this: `UnicodeDecodeError 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xXX`. But if I do this:

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-i", param1, "-o", param2], ..., ...)
```

It works always.

Now I'm using the second method as it works always but I want to understand why the first method doesn't work.

Things I tried:

- Using decode() and decode("utf8") in param1 and param2.
- Using cmd.encode("ascii") when passing cmd to os.system or subprocess.call
- `unset LANG` in terminal prior to run the script (somebody solved a similar problem doing that, so I tried it too)

More info:

This all started when I needed to query a mysql database for a path to a certain directory. The table uses UTF-8. At first I did not specify the encoding when establishing the connection to the database, this results in paths not found when they contain non ASCII characters. For example the word "Vídeos" was decoded as "V\XXXeos" where `\XXX` is the code of the "í" character. When I started to specify the encoding when connecting to the database the non English words looked correctly when printed but the UnicodeDecodeError started to raise when trying to use those strings in calls to os.system or subprocess.call if the command line is build by concatenating strings.

Python 2.7
Mythbuntu 32 bits

Comment: I suspect that the strings are being passed 'uninspected' to the underlying C subprocess dispatch routine. If you try to concatenate them in Python, however, Python will need to actually figure out what data they represent. Basically, there's no error in the second case because Python never even actually looks at the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting a command string (into `argc` and `argv`, i.e. a dynamically sized array of strings, as expected by C programs) is the job of the shell, and different shells have different rules about how to interpret a particular string. `subprocess.call` does not invoke subprocesses in a new subshell by default; instead, it creates a new process directly, and therefore does not know how to interpret your command, so you must pass an array directly.

You can make `subprocess.call` execute in a subshell by passing `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Regarding encodings, yes, it is the responsibility of the program being called to interpret the string encoding of the arguments. If you've set UTF-8 everywhere, it should just work:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("echo 字", shell=True)
字
0
>>> subprocess.call(u"echo 字", shell=True)
字
0
>>> subprocess.call(["echo", "字"])
字
0
>>> subprocess.call([u"echo", u"字"])
字
0
```

Comment: Then in the second case, the strings are untouched because is the responsibility of the process being called to understand their encoding? If I use shell=True I will get same behaviour than with os.system, for example the * character will be processed by the shell first? Then only thing that bothers me is that my terminal is set to UTF-8, my py file is in UTF-8 too, and I'm using # coding: utf-8 at the beginning of the file. Both ways of executing an external command should simply work, isn't?

Comment: OK, now I not remember if my first attempt to use subprocess.call included shell=True. The original lines where already deleted so I cannot check. If I forgot the shell=True then the result should be a message saying "File not found exception 'echo 字'" or similar. I don't remember that error, only the UnicodeDecodeError. But may be may memory betraying me. If I saw the file not found exception as result of my first attempt to use subprocess.call then everything is explained.

Comment: What about os.system? Is python forcing ASCII for compatibility with some platforms? I did not found it in its documentation.

Comment: @HatoruHansou Your `UnicodeDecodeError` is a result of concatenating `str` with `unicode`, e.g. `u"echo" + "字"`, and not specific to `subprocess.call` or `os.system`. This process normally produces a `unicode` object, with the assumption that the `str` is encoded in ASCII. Therefore, python does not know how to decode `"字"` with ASCII because it's UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I understand now. The exception is raised at string concatenation. For example, this works: `u"echo " + "字".decode("utf8")`. Without call to decode `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised. I tried with decode in my script too without success but now I'm not sure which variables I was decoding maybe I missed one causing the exception during concatenation.